# TypeScript: Property 'range' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Type declared in `vscode-languageserver-protocol`:

```js
export declare type TextDocumentContentChangeEvent = {
    /**
     * The range of the document that changed.
     */
    range: Range;
    /**
     * The optional length of the range that got replaced.
     *
     * @deprecated use range instead.
     */
    rangeLength?: number;
    /**
     * The new text for the provided range.
     */
    text: string;
} | {
    /**
     * The new text of the whole document.
     */
    text: string;
};
```

And `change` instance as `TextDocumentContentChangeEvent`, when I use `change.range`, VSCode posts an error that: `Property 'range' does not exist on type '{ text: string; }'`.

How can I check `change.range` or anything I used wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextDocumentContentChangeEvent` is one of two types, only one of which has a `range` property. You'll need to check which kind you have. If you just need `range`, then you can check for that with `in`:

```
if ("range" in change) {
    // You can use change.range here
}
```

Since only one side of the union has `range`, TypeScript is smart enough to know that inside the `if` block, the full type of `change` is the first type (the one with range, rangeLength, and text), so you don't necessarily have to check for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

There now 2 methods in `TextDocumentContentChangeEvent` **namespace**:

`isIncremental` and `isFull`, to check whether `change` has `range` and `rangeLength` or only `text`.